# Calculate the weighted average in pandas with NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with NaN values in it like

```
1 100 200 300
2 150 250 nan
3 175 275 375
```

I have the weights in a series which doesn't have NaNs and have the same index (1,2,3) like

```
1 3
2 4
3 7
```

I want to calculate the weighted sum so that the output doesn't consider the NaN as 0 and divide with the complete sum of the weights i.e 14 and instead divide by 10 which the sum of all weights barring the values which are NaN in corresponding dataframe.

For example, the output of the above calculation should be a dataframe/series like

```
1 151.79
2 251.79
3 352.5
```

The code that I have written till now

```
df.mul(s,axis=0).sum()/s.sum()
```

This gives the result as

```
1 151.79
2 251.79
3 251.79
```

Answer (score 3):

You can mask out the weights where the values are `nan`:

```
weights = df.notna().mul(s, axis=0)
df.mul(weights).sum().div(weights.sum(axis=0))
```

Output:

```
1    151.785714
2    251.785714
3    352.500000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy`:

```
a = df.values
m = ~np.isnan(a)
w = m*s.values.reshape(-1,1)
pd.Series(np.nansum(a * w / w.sum(axis=0), axis=0))
```

Output:

```
0    151.785714
1    251.785714
2    352.500000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), a masked array and [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html#numpy.ma.average):

```
out = pd.Series(np.ma.average(np.ma.masked_array(df, mask=df.isna()),
                              weights=s,
                              axis=0), index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
1    151.785714
2    251.785714
3    352.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @BigBen Oops typo I use `np.average` not `np.ma.average` as I had linked to. Thanks for checking!