# Calculate the average relative humidity over the full timespan covered in the data, dropping any NaN values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

The file named

```
[CSV_NAME]
```

contains hourly weather observations from Jyväskylä, Finland.

| Abbreviation | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| TA | Temperature Average |
| RH | Relative Humidity |
| WS | Wind Speed |
| WD | Wind Direction |
| PRA | Precipitation Amount |
| PRI | Precipitation Intensity |
| PA | Pressure Average |
| WAWA | Most Significant Weather Code |

Calculate the average relative humidity over the full timespan covered in the data, dropping any NaN values.

Please write the answer in number only

Didn’t understand what written about csv_name. What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
If you don't understand the question, check with your teacher. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read CSV files, read RH and drop NA Values.

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path) //put CSV into a data frame
clean_RH = df['RH'].dropna() //goes over the entire RH column and drops NA values
average_RH = clean_RH.mean()
```

> Didn’t understand what written about csv_name. What does it mean?

I am not entirely sure what you're trying to ask here but I'm pretty sure `csv_name` is just trying to refer to the name of the CSV file.

You might find this thread helpful: [Calculate the weighted average in pandas with NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908196/calculate-the-weighted-average-in-pandas-with-nan-values?rq=2)